# I can't enter information from form to database

Tags: php

`I am trying to enter data to database from a registration form but it seems not working and I think I did the right coding I'm not sure where I did wrong I read code by code and all the database I created did follow .

```
<form method='post' action='login.php'>
<table width='400' border='5' align='CENTER'>

<tr>
<td><h1>Registration</h1></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>User Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='name'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='pass'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='email'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='submit' name='register' value='register'/></td>

</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("users_db", $connect); 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $users_name = $_POST['name'];
    $users_pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $users_email = $_POST['email'];

    if($users_name==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your Username')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    if($users_pass==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your password')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    if($users_email==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $check_email="select*from 
    users where 
    users_email='$users_email'";

    $run = 
    mysql_query($check_email) or
    die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    echo"<script>alert('Email $users_email 
    is already exist in our databse, please try another 
    one')</script>";  exit();
    }


    $query = "insert into users 
    (users_name,users_pass,users_email) values('
    $users_name','$users_pass','$users_email')";


    { 
        $result = mysql_query($query) 
        or die(mysql_error());
    }

    echo"<script>alert
    window.open('','_self')</script>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing `$query` and running the final query in phpMyAdmin or whatever other database tools you have to make sure it is correct?

Comment: I don't see any `INSERT` statements. So no data will ever go into your DB

Comment: @Machavity look for `$query` in the code.

Comment: Do you really have a newline before `$users_name` in the query?

Comment: In the $check_email query you should add spaces around the *.

Comment: yup i added space but still not working @LajosVeres

Comment: You have to tell us about the HTML form you use to submit the data. Where it is in relation to the PHP page and what's its action attribute and method attribute.

Comment: How did this get a +1?

Answer (score 1):

Change the initial assignments to:

```
$users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$users_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

to avoid problems with special characters in the fields, as well as to protect against SQL injection.

Change the insert query to:

```
$query = "insert into users (users_name,users_pass,users_email)
          values('$users_name','$users_pass','$users_email')";
```

You had an extraneous newline and spaces before `$users_name`, so these were being inserted into the database.

Comment: i tried but still the same result no database are entered from the form

Comment: What happens if you `echo $query` and then run it by hand in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes I think that data does not delivered well to the PHP. I think the form does not has get attribute, so $_POST does not receive any data.

Comment: i added echo $query = "insert into users (users_name,users_pass,users_email)
          values('$users_name','$users_pass','$users_email')";

Comment: still the same no data entered

Comment: Check Your HTML form again.

Comment: That should display the query SQL. What does it display?

Comment: You just has to `echo $query;`

Comment: this is my html coding

Comment: Don't try to put HTML in the comment, update your question

Comment: i cant post the coding here

Comment: Well, what is the name of your php file that execute the PHP code you regarded?

Comment: http://localhost/registration.php

Comment: Wow, this is your mistake. You have to check again how HTML forms works. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: i dont see any mistake?

Comment: You have to know what's the meaning of `action` attribute of an HTML form!

Comment: <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> thats what i did

Comment: <form method='post' action='login.php'>

Comment: `action='registration.php'`

Comment: i change it but still not workng

Comment: Change your PHP to just `<?php echo "This is the PHP script;" ?>` and see if that works. I want to make sure you're getting into the right script.

Comment: yup tried that but nor working it also came out this

Comment: This is the PHP script

Comment: Then I can't explain why the original script isn't working. With all the changes we suggested, it should work. You must not be copying them properly.