# Creating Registration form

Tags: php, mysql, registration

HI i've got an error on line 20  **i have tried mysqli**

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 20`

```
    <html>
<body>
<?php
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['register']))
$username= strip_tags(trim(mysql_real_ecape_string($_POST['username'])));
$password= strip_tags(trim(mysql_real_ecape_string($_POST['password'])));

    if(!username || !$password){
    echo "One of the fields are empty";
    }else{
    $find_multiple=" SELECT Username FROM register WHERE Username='$username' ";
    $run_multiple = mysql_query($find_multiple) or die (mysql_error());
    $num_multiple= mysql_num_rows($run_multiple);

    if($num_multiple < 1){
    $password= md5($password)

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO register SET Username='$Username', Password='$Pasword' ") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "You have succesfully registered!":

    }else{
    echo "That username has already beed used" ;

    }

?>  


<h1>Register</h1>
<form action='' method='post'>
username: <input type='text' name'username'/></br>
Password: <input type='password' name'password'/></br>
<input type='submit' value='Register'name='register'/>
</form>
```

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 13

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("users", $connect); 


    if(isset($_POST['register'])){


    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

        if(!$username || !$password){
        echo "One of the fields are empty";
        }else{
        $find_multiple=" SELECT username FROM resgistration WHERE username='$username' ";
        $run_multiple = mysql_query($find_multiple) or die (mysql_error());
        $num_multiple= mysql_num_rows($run_multiple);

        if($num_multiple < 1){
        $password= md5($password);

        mysql_query( "INSERT INTO `resgistration` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."')" ) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "You have succesfully registered!";

        }else{
            echo "That username has already beed used" ;
    } 

         } # endelse: empty password or username
    } # endif: registered
    ?>  
    <head>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action='' method='post'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username'/></br>
    password: <input type='password' name='password'/></br>
    <input type='submit' value='Register'name='register'/>

    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the question...

Comment: In your case you are missing a `;` on the line before.

Comment: Please stop spamming your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437794/i-cant-enter-information-from-form-to-database

Answer (score 0):

Missing ; in this line:

```
$password= md5($password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a semi-colon on the preceding line. PHP uses `;` as statement terminators, and they're not optional.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon after this line:

```
$password= md5($password)
```

You also have a colon (should be a semicolon) after:

```
 echo "You have succesfully registered!":
```

You should read about [how to debug PHP errors by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php), so that you can start fixing simple bugs like this.

Answer (score 0):

you missed semicolon in line 19.

also INSERT INTO [TABLE] SET is not standard somehow.
try this format:

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `register` (`username`, `password`) VALUES 
               ('$username', '$password')");
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 38

Comment: seems you missed `code`}`code` also the whole line would be:    `code`mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'register' ('username', 'password') VALUES 
               ('$username', '$password')"); or die(mysql_error()); `code`

Comment: i tried mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'register' ('username', 'password') VALUES ('$username', '$password')");  die(mysql_error());

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 42

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("users", $connect); 

    if( isset( $_POST['hide'] ) && $_POST['hide'] == 1 ) {

        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];

        if( !$username || !$password ) {
            echo "One of the fields are empty";
        } else {
            $find_multiple = "SELECT username FROM resgistration WHERE username = '".$username."'";
            $run_multiple = mysql_query( $find_multiple ) or die ( mysql_error() );

            if( mysql_num_rows( $run_multiple ) == 0 ) {
                $password= md5($password);

                mysql_query( "INSERT INTO `resgistration` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."')" ) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "You have succesfully registered!";
            } else {
                echo "That username has already beed used" ;
            } 

        } # endelse: empty password or username
    } # endif: registered
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <tilte>Registration</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
            Username: <input type='text' name='username'/></br>
            password: <input type='password' name='password'/></br>
            <input type='hidden' name='hide' value='1' />
            <input type='submit' value='Register' name='register'/>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 42

Comment: can you give the code where getting syntax error???

Comment: mysql_query( "INSERT INTO `register` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."')" ) (die(mysql_error());
 echo "You have succesfully registered!";

Comment: and i tired mysql_query( "INSERT INTO `register` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."')" ) or die(mysql_error());
 echo "You have succesfully registered!";

Comment: can you check my second code?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 12 Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

At:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO register SET Username='$Username', Password='$Pasword' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

You missed an s at `$Pasword`

Also you are using capital letters and when you declare them, you dont use capital letters...

So use:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO register SET Username='$username', Password='$password' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

You also have:

```
 $password= md5($password)
```

Which should be:

```
 $password= md5($password);
```

That would fix your error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query'

Also Rohit is right about the:

1) Replace

```
if(!username || !$password)
```

With

```
if(!$username || !$password)
```

By the way. Don't use mysql...

**EDIT:**

Now that I notice it, you aren't closing the

```
else{
```

at:

```
if(!username || !$password){
    echo "One of the fields are empty";
    }else{
```

AND phpcoder is right about the:

```
echo "You have succesfully registered!":
```

Should be

```
echo "You have succesfully registered!";
```

I didn't notice it myself.

**2nd EDIT:**

This was the answer on his problem he had before. He updated the question with the mistakes gone now.

Comment: i done that can you check my eddited code? i got  Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Users\User\l\htdocs\register.php on line 13

Comment: @dean012 I've had the same problem once and it was something with the mysql real escape string as I recall, but can't remember anymore. It looks normal.